# inject dbcontext to owin middleware

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac

I implemented `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. I inject `IOAuthService` (my service for authentication) to implementation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.
Implementation of IOAuthService gives DbContext through parameter of contructor. So, OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider gives DbContext as a singleton.

How can I inject `DbContext` to my implementation `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` using `Autofac` with per web request scope?

If I try to register `dbcontext` using following code:

```
builder.RegisterType<OAuthProviderContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerWebRequest();
```

then I will get an error: new scope could not be associated with HttpRequest.

```
public class ADAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private readonly IAppSettings _appSettingsProvider;
        private readonly IOAuthServiceProvider _oauthServiceProvider;

    public ADAuthorizationServerProvider(IAppSettings appSettingsProvider, 
        IOAuthServiceProvider oauthServiceProvider)
    {
        _appSettingsProvider = appSettingsProvider;
        _oauthServiceProvider = oauthServiceProvider;
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
       //code
    }

public class OAuthServiceProvider : IOAuthServiceProvider
    {
        private readonly IRefreshTokenRepository _refreshTokenRepository;
        private readonly IClientRepository _clientRepository;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork; 



    public OAuthServiceProvider(IRefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository,
        IClientRepository clientRepository,
        IUserRepository userRepository,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository;
        _clientRepository = clientRepository;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;            
    }

    public async Task AddRefreshToken(RefreshToken token)
    {
      //code...            
    }

    public async Task DeleteRefreshToken(string tokenId)
    {
       //code...
    }

    public async Task<Client> FindClient(string clientName)
    {
     //code...
    }

    public async Task<RefreshToken> FindRefreshToken(string tokenId)
    {
      //code...
    }

    public async Task<User> FindUser(string username)
    {
    //code...
    }
}

public class ClientRepository : BaseReadonlyRepository<Guid, Client>,       IClientRepository
{
   public ClientRepository(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public async Task<Client> GetByName(string name)
    {
       //code...
    }
}

public class RefreshTokenRepository : BaseRepository<string, RefreshToken>, IRefreshTokenRepository
{
    public RefreshTokenRepository(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
}

public class UserRepository : BaseReadonlyRepository<Guid, User>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public async Task<User> GetByName(string username)
    {
       //code...
    }
}

builder.RegisterType<OAuthProvider>().As<DbContext> ().InstancePerLifetimeScope() //I give DbContext as singleton here.
```

`

Comment: Can you include your relevant code?

Comment: And format it properly ...

Comment: Stack trace? Full exception? Also, the question says you're using `InstancePerWebRequest` but the code says `InstancePerLifetimeScope` - which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a feature provided by Autofac that will *wrap* the `OAuthAuthroizationServerMiddleware`. That way the OAuth middleware and all its dependencies will be instantiated by Autofac for each request, so no singletons are involved.

Please have a read through the [relevant documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/owin.html#dependency-injection-in-middleware) and a sample I put together in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/mderriey/autofac-owin-middleware).